# Which of these approaches is better for breaking Spring Boot applications into three tiers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, ejb

We are trying to split a big monolithic J2EE application into a set of modules to provide unified business logic for all web application clients.

Our goal is to have smaller and more specialized business modules that can be used in any combination by many distinct web applications. This way we expect the applications get easier to maintain individually (compared to the now heavily coupled monolithic one).

We are planning to arrange it like the following diagram:

[image: Applications diagram]

Where Web Apps call module services on the upper layer to handle business logic through method calls (RMI was the intended protocol but we are open to other options).

J2EE makes it easy to arrange services on three tiers like this through EJB remote beans.

But we are also trying to setup these modules as spring boot applications (using the [Spring Boot JPA Starter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa)) because it makes development much more convenient.

My initial plan was to implement the modules with Spring Boot and expose a thin layer of EJB beans as proxies to spring beans with the actual implementation of the service. EJB beans would have spring beans injected using the `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor` class [as in spring v4 documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html).

But since this kind of integration [was removed from spring v5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21361) I don't know how to proceed.

They are also considering "EJB as an effectively deprecated technology now" as stated in the issue above. But for my use case I can't find a good enough alternative.

So far I have thought of the following options:

1. Using a custom interceptor as the issue suggests. But it looks like reinventing a discarded old wheel (if that analogy makes any sense).
2. [Spring remoting](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/remoting.html) is an alternative but it's challenging to make it work with Wildfly JNDI for RMI configuration and trying to looks like re-implementing EJB remoting.
3. [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) I think will add too much complexity and overhead for this simple task.
4. Message based integration (JMS, MQTT, etc...) may not fit well because of the synchronous nature of what we are trying to achieve.
5. REST API calls would add a lot of boilerplate code (for serialization and deserialization of objects into JSON, endpoints configuration and so on) and also add some ovehead because the HTTP handling.

Our goals, in this order of priority, are:

1. Make this integration as solid and fail-proof as possible.
2. Make calls to business logic from the web layer to the service layer as simple as possible.
3. Have as little overhead as possible.

With all that said which of those five options mentioned (or maybe another one I haven't considered) would be the best way and why?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "We are trying to split a big monolithic J2EE application into a set of modules to provide unified business logic for all web application clients"? What are the goals for the split?

Comment: Provided a little more details on the second paragraph. Since I created this post we made some progress. Currently we implemented option one. But we still question if this was the best approach.